# Tab/Enter/Arrow keys and control focus problems with WPF Datagrid and adjacent controls

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

I have a datagrid in WPF Application.

My DataGrid is bound to a Collection of Person called People as shown in the code below :

Person.cs

```
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Person> _people;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> People
    {
        get
        {
            return _people;
        }
        set
        {
            _people = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("People");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window .......
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="65*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="9*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="93*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="14*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid x:Name="maindg" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding People}" Margin="0,0,0.4,-0.2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                  PreviewKeyDown="DataGrid_KeyDown_1" SelectedIndex="0" GridLinesVisibility="Vertical" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader" GotFocus="maindg_GotFocus" LostFocus="maindg_LostFocus" />

        <Button Height="20" Width="50" Content="Save" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="btnSave" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private int FindRowIndex(DataGridRow row)
    {
        DataGrid dataGrid =
            ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(row)
            as DataGrid;

        int index = dataGrid.ItemContainerGenerator.
            IndexFromContainer(row);

        return index;
    }

    private object ExtractBoundValue(DataGridRow row,
                             DataGridCell cell)
    {
        // find the column that this cell belongs to
        DataGridBoundColumn col =
           cell.Column as DataGridBoundColumn;

        // find the property that this column is bound to
        Binding binding = col.Binding as Binding;
        string boundPropertyName = binding.Path.Path;

        // find the object that is related to this row
        object data = row.Item;

        // extract the property value
        PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
            TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(data);

        PropertyDescriptor property = properties[boundPropertyName];
        if (property != null)
        {
            object value = property.GetValue(data);

            return value;
        }

        return null;
    }

    private void DataGrid_KeyDown_1(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key != Key.Enter) return;

        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;
        //here we just find the cell got focused ...
        //then we can use the cell key down or key up
        // iteratively traverse the visual tree
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridCell) && !(dep is DataGridColumnHeader))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep == null)
            return;

        if (dep is DataGridCell)
        {
            try
            {
                //cancel if datagrid in edit mode
                maindg.CommitEdit();


                //Check if selected cell is on first column and last row
                if (maindg.CurrentColumn.DisplayIndex == 0)
                {
                    DependencyObject dep1 = dep;
                    while ((dep1 != null) && !(dep1 is DataGridRow))
                    {
                        dep1 = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep1);
                    }

                    DataGridRow row = dep1 as DataGridRow;

                    if (FindRowIndex(row) == maindg.Items.Count - 1)
                    {
                        if (ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell) == null || ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell).ToString().Trim() == "")
                        {
                            btnSave.Focus();
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell) == null || ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell).ToString().Trim() == "")
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                maindg.CancelEdit();
            }
            //get current cell
            DataGridCell cell = dep as DataGridCell;
            //deselect current cell
            cell.IsSelected = false;
            //find next right cell
            var nextCell = cell.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Right);
            //if next right cell null go for find next ro first cell
            if (nextCell == null)
            {
                DependencyObject nextRowCell;
                nextRowCell = cell.PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Down);
                //if next row is null so we have no more row Return;
                if (nextRowCell == null)
                {
                    nextRowCell = dep;
                    while ((nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left) != null)
                        nextRowCell = (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left);
                    //change current cell
                    maindg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextRowCell as DataGridCell);
                    //change selected cell
                    (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).IsSelected = true;
                    return;
                }
                //we do this because we cant use FocusNavigationDirection.Next for function PredictFocus
                //so we have to find it this way
                while ((nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left) != null)
                    nextRowCell = (nextRowCell as DataGridCell).PredictFocus(FocusNavigationDirection.Left);
                //set new cell as next cell
                nextCell = nextRowCell;
            }

            //change current cell
            maindg.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(nextCell as DataGridCell);
            //change selected cell
            (nextCell as DataGridCell).IsSelected = true;
            // start edit mode
            maindg.BeginEdit();
        }
        //handl the default action of keydown
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    private void maindg_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!maindg.CanUserAddRows)
        {
            maindg.CanUserAddRows = true;
        }
    }

    private void maindg_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!maindg.IsKeyboardFocusWithin && maindg.CanUserAddRows)
        {
            maindg.CanUserAddRows = false;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code above, I have used the three events of the DataGrid namely : PreviewKeyDown, GotFocus and LostFocus.

I have used PreviewKeyDown Event because I want to act my <kbd>Enter</kbd> as <kbd>TAB</kbd>. Also  for the focus purposes. You will understand it in a bit.

Actually, my DataGrid contains 3 Auto-generated columns. When I enter data in 3rd cell of any row, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a new row should be added as CanUsersAddRows is set to true by default. But the focus of the third goes to the third cell of the newly created row. But I want the focus to be on the first cell of the newly created row. I have achieved that successfully by using PreviewKeyDown Event in the code mentioned above.

I have also tried to achieve the below thing. When the focus is on the first cell of the last row, and if I leave that cell empty and if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the focus should on the  button declared outside Grid. I have achieved this thing Partially. Why I have used the word Partially???? For that see Problems Section below.

I have used GotFocus and LostFocus Events in the above mentioned code because I want to delete the auto-generated row at the end of the DataGrid when DataGrid looses focus. I have achieved the solution to that problem also.

**Problem :**

When I enter some data in the DataGrid, for example : If I enter some data in three rows of the DataGrid. At that time DataGrid's third cell of third row has the focus. Now, when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> a new row is created. Call it fourth row. Now focus is on the fourth row's 1st cell. Now, If I leave that cell empty and Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, the focus is expected to go to Button outside the DataGrid and the fourth row (Autogenerated row) is expected to be deleted. Upto this point my Application works fine.

Now the button outside the DataGrid is focused. Now if I press down arrow key, the focus comes to the third cell of the first row. In short DataGrid gets focus and so CanUserAddRows is turned to true due to code in GotFocus Event of DataGrid. Now if I reach to the first cell of the fourth row, by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> many times, I expect the same behavior as mentioned in the above paragraph. Now if I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> leaving the first cell of the fourth row empty, the focus goes on second cell of the fourth row. But I expect it to go to the Button Outside DataGrid.

**What I have found while debugging :**

When first cell of the fourth row gets focus second time, just before that a new empty Person is added to the People Collection. and so DataGrid no more treats fourth row as AutoGenerated. I don't know how to prevent People collection from adding that row.

**Sample and How to reproduce the issue:**

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5WyqSALui0beU5YWWhBTlFja0k/edit?usp=sharing) is my sample project.

To understand my problem clearly please follow the below steps:

1. Download the sample app and run it.
2. Add some data to the DataGrid as follows:

   <kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>B</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>D</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>F</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>G</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>H</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>I</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   <kbd>Enter</kbd>

   Focus will go to the button. Press down arrow key. Now again press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> as many times as you reach the first cell of the fourth row. As the first cell of the fourth row is empty, the focus is expected to go to the button but it continues to the next cell of the grid. I am trying to sort out the problem from last 15 hours or so. But I am unsuccessful. Please give me some guidance on this problem.

Comment: Have you tried to debug your code, especially the method *DataGrid_KeyDown_1* ? Most certainly you would find out why the save button is not being focused anymore by just stepping through the code...

Comment: @elgonzo  Yes, I have debugged it and found that : When I get the expected behavior `FindRowIndex(row) == maindg.Items.Count - 1` returns true, but when I get unexpected behavior `FindRowIndex(row) == maindg.Items.Count - 1` returns false as the autogenerated row is added to the People collection. But I don't know why WPF is doing so?

Comment: Note that the auto-generated row is treated as temporary as long as it has not been in edit mode (thus it will appear/disappear when you toggle the *CanUserAddRows* property. As soon as it has been in edit mode once, it is becomes a normal/permanent row, and a new temporary row is being created. A workaround would require to remove that empty row... and that is not so easy - because edit mode of this row can be left by various means, either another row becomes current/selected via keyboard/mouse navigation or the cell loses the input focus... in any of those events you should do the following:

Comment: Check if the last row (or the row before the last row) has only empty cells. If it is the case, schedule an action on the dispatcher which removes this empty row from the item collection (like `dataGrid.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() => dataGrid.Items.RemoveAt(rowIndex)));`) -- it is safer to use the dispatcher, as it cannot be ruled out that the datagrid could become confused if you manipulate its items collection while being in an event handler...

Comment: For your handling of the Enter key, it would be sufficient to test for `if (FindRowIndex(row) == maindg.Items.Count - 2)` (note the **2**). If successful, delete the row if it is empty (as described in the previous comment), and then proceed with setting focus to the button and return. Still, in the grander scheme of things you would need to figure something out regarding deleting the empty row in the situation where the selected row changes due to mouse navigation or the datagrid losing focus.

Comment: In case you don't know how you can access all cells of a row (necessary if you want to check if a row is empty), you might want to read this blog article: [Get WPF DataGrid row and cell](http://techiethings.blogspot.de/2010/05/get-wpf-datagrid-row-and-cell.html)

Comment: Attention: If *ItemsSource* is not *null*, you cannot use the *dataGrid.Items* collection to remove a row, but you will need to cast *ItemsSource* to *IList* and remove the item of that row there...

Comment: I don't know, but perhaps it is even easier to let CanUserAddRows=False and manage the last row entirely in your code (by adding/removing an empty item to the ItemsSource/Items collection as necessary)

Comment: @elgonzo my problem is solved by following the answer given by RohitVats. Thanks for trying to give me some suggestions on solving the problem.

Comment: RohitVats answer is amazing, indeed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is some discrepancy in the behaviour written in the question and provided in sample:

> I entered some data in first cell of first row and press Enter,
>   instead of focus moving to second cell of first row, it moves to first
>   cell of second row.

To fix this issue get rid of this else statement:

```
else
{
   if (ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell) == null
       || ExtractBoundValue(row, dep as DataGridCell).ToString().Trim() == "")
   {
       return;
   }
}
```

This statement stops second cell to get focus when enter is pressed on first cell of any row.

---

Now, to your actual problem. Issue is when you press enter on last cell of third row, first cell of fourth row goes into edit mode. Hence, results in creating instance of Person object. Before putting the row in edit mode, first check if row is **`NewItemPlaceholder`** or not.

Replace last line

```
// start edit mode
maindg.BeginEdit();
```

with this one which checks for **`NewItemPlaceholder`** and if not then only put row in edit mode:

```
DependencyObject selectedRow = nextCell;
while ((selectedRow != null) && !(selectedRow is DataGridRow))
{
    selectedRow = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(selectedRow);
}
if ((selectedRow as DataGridRow).Item.ToString() != "{NewItemPlaceholder}")
{
    // start edit mode
    maindg.BeginEdit();
}
```

Comment: you are very much intellegent. I don't have any words to thank you. Thanks very very much.

Comment: Sorry for asking you but I have got same problem with some different behavior by user. Let me explain you. For example I enter data in DataGrid and fill its 3 rows. Now I Press Enter. Focus is now on the first cell of the fourth row. Now if I enter some data in this cell and delete it immediately. That means cell is still empty. Now If I press enter the focus will move to next cell instead I expect it to go to the button outside the datagrid. If you become free then please have a look at this problem.

Comment: Issue is when you bring the cell in edit mode, a Person object gets created. So issue is same consider you enter one row values. Focus on second row, now go back to first row and delete the content from all cells. It's now equivalent to the scenario which you are describing above. So, what you have to do is check for null value and manually delete the object from the collection. You can also hook event `CellEditEnding` to validate such scenarios.

Comment: Yes you are absolutely right. But I am developing a thing like customControl. So, I don't want the xxxxx.xaml.cs file to know something about the Collection that is present in ViewModel. So, I think I cannot manually delete the object from the collection. Is there any other way?